# Resume Download Links in PHP

Tags: php

The following file (which I don't understand it at all) serves my requested file and makes it ready to be downloaded. But, the links that are created and served by this file miss really important items when downloading by IDM.

File size: (unknown), Time left (unknown) , Resume capability (unknown).

Very unprofessional and bad in all aspects. What should I do as a novice?

```
if (isset($status) && ($status == 'd')) {  //if Every Thing Is Fine The Download Start 

$filename = $url;
$extension = fileexten($filename);

$fakename = fakefilename($downcode);

$mime = contenttype($extension);

// set_time_limit(0);
if ($notadownload == FALSE) {
    header('Pragma: public');

    header('Expires: 0');

    header("Content-Type:" . $mime);

    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=' . $fakename . '.' . $extension);

    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    ob_clean();

    flush();

    @readfile($filename);

} else {

    $mime = getContentType($filename);
    header("Content-Type:" . $mime);

    if (strpos($mime, 'text') == FALSE) {
        $extension = fileexten($filename);
        header('Content-Disposition: inline;filename=' . $fakename . '.' . $extension);
    }

    echo @file_get_contents($filename);

}
}
```

Comment: File size - `header("Content-Length: ".filesize($fileUrl));` Time left (unknown) , Resume capability (unknown). - No idea

Comment: @David Not to see **unknown** file size, time,left or resume. That's clear dude!

Comment: Yes, and so were your comments under your latest question (that you just removed.) Sorry, but the mere fact that you seem to be in way over your head does not make it our responsibility to fix it. While it may be clear what you are basically _asking_ here, it does not come close to the requirements outlined in [ask] regarding what we expect you to do in order to try and solve the issue yourself _prior_ to coming here. If you have been thrown into a project "above your pay grade", then you need to take that up with however made that decision.